# How we go from food argument to printing Fruits values by my_function?

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

```
def my_function(food):
  for x in food:
    print(x)

fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

my_function(fruits)
```

I'm on https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

I just don't understand how we go from food to printing fruits. my_function is (food). How does it become Fruits?

Comment: `fruits` is the name of the variable that is passed in as an argument to the function.  `food` is the name that the function assigns to its parameter.  The two names do not have to be the same.  This is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new myself, but the best way I can describe it is:

You made a function called `my_function()` which in this case takes in the input of `food` shown by the parentheses brackets. `my_function(food)`

So whenever you want to call `my_function()` later down the line, you will be *required* to give it an input.

The input in this case can be any *iterable* things. (strings, lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries, etc)

Iterables are anything that you can loop over.
More on iterables : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/07/everything-you-should-know-about-iterables-and-iterators-in-python-as-a-data-scientist/

So in a sense, `food` *means* `fruits`.

And `x` "turns" into each iterable value, first as `apple` then prints itself, then turns into `banana` and prints itself, etc.

For example, try to add a variable `word = 'Poptart'`
Then you can call `my_function()` using `word` by typing `my_function(word)` which will give you

```
P
o
p
t
a
r
t
```

You can also look at W3School's loop page https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Hope this helps in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code:

```
def my_function(food):
  for x in food:
    print(x)

fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

my_function(fruits)
```

The first three lines define (`def`) a function. In this case, the function is named `my_function`. Python looks at the whitespace starting the second and third line, and sees that you want these to be part of `my_function`.

`my_function` takes a single argument which can be provided by another part of your code when it wants to run the function. The label it uses for this argument is `food`.

Looking at the code inside the function

```
for x in food:
  print(x)
```

the function is expecting a list that it can iterate over, passing each value from the list to the print function.

Now that you have the function defined, you can run it from the rest of the code.

In this case, there are two other things the code does:

1. It defines a variable called `fruits` and assigns it a list of strings - "apple", "banana", and "cherry".
2. It then runs the function `my_function` with the argument being the variable `fruits`.

So when the function runs, the argument that it receives from the rest of the code is the list which is contained in `fruits`, but it can refer to it locally as `food` and perform the operations on that list that it does (which is printing all the items in the list).

If you consider the following code, it may be easier to see why we do this:

```
def my_function(food):
  for x in food:
    print(x)

fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

vegetables = ["lettuce", "carrot", "potato"]

my_function(fruits)

my_function(vegetables)
```

Here, we define two lists `fruits` and `vegetables`. We then run the function `my_function` providing each of these, but the function only ever knows the argument as `food`. That way it can do all the same operations (printing the items in the list) without needing to know what we called the variable in the rest of the code.

Hopefully that helped. If I've made a mess of the explanation or you have any other questions, let me know!